# HTML5 video element not looping when indicating time start+time end

Tags: html, video

I have a simple video source in html:

```
<div id="videoBG--wrapper">
<div id="video_overlay"></div>
<video loop id="videoBG" poster="/imgs/green_tree.png" autoplay muted >
    <source src="/videos/van_island_1080.mp4#t=23,28" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
```

Once I remove `#t=23,28` loop works.

Any idea why this is happening and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested your code but I don't think that `#t=23,28` will set a loop range as easily as you think.

You could use your `#startTime` with `ontimeupdate` to create a looping video effect.

- `ontimeupdate` is updated every time when the video's *currentTime* changes, so use it to check if the `#endTime` is reached, then seek video to your preferred starting time.

Try setting your code like this example:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="videoBG--wrapper">
<div id="video_overlay"></div>
<video loop id="videoBG" poster="/imgs/green_tree.png" autoplay muted ontimeupdate="myLooper(this)" 
source src="/videos/van_island_1080.mp4#t=23" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>

<script>

var myvid = document.getElementById("videoBG");

function myLooper(event) 
{
    //# IF endTime (seconds) reached THEN seek back to startTime
    if ( event.currentTime > 28 ) { myvid.currentTime = 23; }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: You might have to tweak that `event.currentTime > 28` into a `29` or even try using fractions like eg: `28.5` to get a seamless loop.